# OctoberCMS: How to know whether user was logged in or registered in social login plugin?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am using the [Social Login Plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/flynsarmy-sociallogin) to login/register with Google accounts. If user is registered for the first time, I want to redirect them to the "Edit Profile" page so that they can complete their profile info, and if they are not a new user and just logged in, I want to redirect them to the home page after successful login. How can I check if the user is new? Maybe we need a new event like `flynsarmy.sociallogin.afterRegister`? I tried listening to `rainlab.user.register` but it didn't fire after user was registered.

Comment: You can probably hook into the ``create`` event of the ``User`` model, can't you? The event you mentionned is beeing fired in the component ( https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin/blob/master/components/Account.php#L237 ) and will thus not execute if you use a social provider.

Comment: @AlexGuth `rainlab.user.register` should be fired because `Auth::register()` is called in the plugin to register a new user.

Comment: Auth::register() does not fire this event, if I am not totally missreading the code. It is actually fired in the component itself. This is why you can't catch it.

Answer (score 1):

What I get in mind for now is that just from your own plugin extend User table (add extra column first_time or fist_time_register) assign it a default value to "1".

I have seen in code when it try to find user with provider(google, etc)
if it founds it will return and login him and redirect to success page.

if not found register him, login him then redirect to success page.

(problem is that it does not have after register event :( as it has flynsarmy.sociallogin.registerUser but it fires before registration so .. )

so I guess every time user is registered. default will set to 1 and in next request you can get logged in user check this column value and if its 1 redirect to profile page , when user fill profile page in save set this value to 0 so next time flow will be to success page.

**UPDATE**

---

I checked code of rainlabn.user plugin

it will register user using **Auth::register(..args)** then fire event **rainlab.user.register**

Same goes for **oc-sociallogin-plugin** but **but** it will register user using **Auth::register(..args)** then it's not firing **rainlab.user.register** instead it is firing **flynsarmy.sociallogin.registerUser** event and also it fires it before registration method.

so, I guess in this case **rainlab.user.register** will not even fire when user is registered with **oc-sociallogin-plugin** plugin.

I hope this will help in case any issue please comment.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. But before doing that, I think I have to be able to use the Rainlab.User plugin [events](https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin#events). If I could catch the `rainlab.user.register` event, I would be able to know whether user was registered or logged in. Unfortunately though, only the `rainlab.user.login` event is fired when using the social login plugin. Any ideas?

Comment: updated answer please check in update block i guess `rainlab.user.login` will not work as @alex-guth mentioned it.

Comment: Hi and sorry for my late response. I opened a pull request for this: https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin/pull/299 
I will keep you posted about its status :)

Comment: Hmm I see you did lots of discussion, Cool they will surely help to find out some cool solution.